# PUT json объекта на сервер возвращает ошибку

Tags: jquery, json, javascript

Есть у меня такой запрос, который в Chrome Rest Client и FireFox RESTClient отрабатывает

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/bindings/",
        contentType: "Application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: '{ "name": "New binding", "ref-id": "Taiwan-0001" }',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            alert("Error: " + error);
        }
    });
```

В консоле я вижу ошибку:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/bindings. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Не подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка?

Это скриншот удачного выполнения из FireFox:

[image]

Comment: А подскажите, пожалуйста, что это за ПО такое вы используете? Где можно увидеть, все запросы, ошибки и т.д?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить в конфигурацию виртуального хоста apache

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Либо писать заголовки в файлах

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Всё гениальное просто :)

Comment: ок, я работаю с демо сервисом клиента, надо будет им сказать, чтобы добавили еще и Access-Control-Allow-Headers, т.к. была проблема с кросс доменностью, мы их попросили добавить Access-Control-Allow-Origin
_____

Кстати, type: "DELETE" отрабатывает и сейчас.